# Which is the best place to init ViewModel in fragment onCreateView or onCreate Method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using live data with ViewModel.

I have a scenario where I have two fragments and One Activity. 
Fragment A and Fragment B.

From Activity, I have launched Fragment A (its shows list of names i.e fetch from backend) and when I tap on Name its displays Fragment B(that's is back stack).

Now from Fragment B if I press the back button, it returns to fragment A, it shows a blank screen as I have implemented ViewModel in the onCreate method of fragment A.

But if I have implemented the ViewModel in the oncreateView method of fragment A, it will keep on adding observers as the fragment is not destroyed.

Comment: `onActivityCreated`

Comment: why onActivityCreated

Comment: You can guarantee that the Fragment is attached in the activity.

Comment: But it will keep on adding observers

Comment: By using `onActivityCreated` I assume that the ViewModel is shared across fragment.

Comment: Initialize the `ViewModel` inside activity's `onCreate` and call the reference inside Fragment's `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: But that's should lead to boilerplate code

Comment: that's why i am asking if i used in oncreate then it will not show any data as viewmodel init in onCreate

Comment: I think you mean too "verbose" not boilerplate? No that's pretty normal scenario.

Comment: Yeah, verbose, but that's not a good approach isn't?

Comment: It's not a bad approach, the way Fragment communicate to other Fragment is by using a ViewModel that relies on Activity's lifespan, both fragment will attach an observer to that common viewmodel. That ViewModel will act as mediator.

Comment: but when I pressed a back button from Fragment B, if I init ViewModel in oncreate of Fragment A, it will not displays any data.If i placed in onActivity create method it will keep adding observers.

Comment: As I said earlier initialize your ViewModel inside Activity's `onCreate` not in Fragment's `onCreate` then inside Fragment's `onActivityCreated` call that viewModel instance and attach your observer. :)

Comment: But I don't want to initialize from Activity's onCreate method as my activity is independent of fragment's ViewModel.My activity will only launch fragments.

Comment: Sorry I can't really help any further since it matters in your usecase a lot. Probably just try random testing and see which approach might work for your case. Somehow it is hard for me to suggest since I don't know your exact code. Hopefully somebody have better answer than my approach. :)

Comment: Thanks, as per Android doc, init ViewModel in onCreate method of the fragment.

Comment: Not sure why you can't init from activity. What's so bad in adding the observer code there? It's totally fine IMO. Android viewmodel overview doc shows a specific case where 2 fragments share data. This is not applicable if you need to repopulate the 1st fragment data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid keeping additional `Observers` in `onCreateView`, pass `getViewLifecycleOwner()` as the `LifecycleOwner` to the `LiveData`'s `observe` method. This will remove the previous `Observer` as soon as the `fragment`'s `View` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You could **add** fragment B on top of fragment A instead of **replacing** - this way fragment A would still be alive, and all its data won't be missing, and you wouldn't have to call either onCreate or onCreateView.